# Subscript requires size of interface 'NSArray', which is not constant in non-stable ABI

Tags: objective-c, nsarray, asihttprequest

I'm trying to send information to a server using ASIHTTPRequest and am setting the post values like this:

```
    for(int i = 0;i<13;i++){
  [request setPostValue:propertyValues[i] forKey:propertyKeys[i]]    
}
```

propertyValues and propertyKeys are both NSArray objects that hold 13 items each. When I run this, I get the error "Subscript requires size of interface 'NSArray', which is not constant in non-stable ABI"

What does this mean?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It means you're trying to access an `NSArray*` as if it were an array, or a pointer you could do arithmetic with. `x[5]` for pointer types is equivalent to `x + sizeof(x) * 5`. Note the `sizeof` operator - it means the compiler needs to know the size of the type to advance the pointer by 5 "items". However, `NSArray` is an Objective C interface, and the compiler can't be sure what the size of the type is. This explains the wording of the error you're getting.

More prosaically, you can't access `NSArray` objects like that. You need to send them a message asking for the item at a given index, thus:

```
[propertyValues objectAtIndex:i];
```

Comment: Nothing like reviewing basic concepts in the morning! Thanks for the great answer!

Comment: Note, that this is no longer true. As of Xcode 4.5 it's possible to access NSArray elements using [index] directly. See this answer for more details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9347722/what-are-the-details-of-objective-c-literals-mentioned-in-the-xcode-4-4-releas

Answer (score 3):

You cannot access the objects inside an `NSArray` with the square bracket syntax. You have to use

```
[propertyValues objectAtIndex:i]
```

instead.

Comment: Which is to say, you have to use Smalltalk's square bracket syntax, instead. :)

Answer (score 2):

To access elements of NSArray you must use `objectAtIndex:` method

```
for(int i = 0;i<13;i++){
  [request setPostValue:[propertyValues objectAtIndex:i] forKey:[propertyKeys objectAtIndex:i]l    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That's not now you access values in an `NSArray` (which is fundamentally different than a C array).

```
[request setPostValue:[propertyValues objectAtInstance:i] forKey:[propertyKeys objectAtInstance:i]];
```